# How to add css framework into html file with existing basic css

Tags: html, css, css-frameworks, bulma

I'm wondering if you are able to add a css framework, specifically bulma, into an html sheet with existing css.  The current css is just a standard < link > style.css, and I'm wondering if I can just link the bulma https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.5.1/css/bulma.css
 with the same < link > tag just under or above it on the same sheet.

Comment: You should be able to yes.

Comment: Try it...and see the magic happen.

Comment: trying to do before questioning is a better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Starter from Bulma Website
http://bulma.io/documentation/overview/start/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Hello Bulma!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.5.0/css/bulma.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <section class="section">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="title">
        Hello World
      </h1>
      <p class="subtitle">
        My first website with <strong>Bulma</strong>!
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.5.1/css/bulma.css">
```

in the `<head>...</head>` of your html file and it will works

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is probably missing a part.
The part where the question is raised : will this inclusion of the bulma css interfere with the existing style.css?
In that case.. probably.. as soon as pure HTML elements are described in the style.css and return in the bulma.css, for example: table {....} is present in the bulma css, it could cause some strange behavior.
There are several ways to try and bypass this behavior, some of them clean, others less clean :)
First you need to decide whether the bulma is the default css to be used or not... 
If so, use your own style.css to overwrite the bulma.css.
If not, still call your style.css as last css in the row.. items that are not defined in your stylesheet will be taken care of by the bulma css

Comment: I'm a bit sad that my answer got a downvote... I just pointed out that inserting another css that contains same basic elements will cause styles to change. unless you apply !important to the once you don't want to change.